# Why do we walk down the aisle at a wedding

Tags: minhag, history, wedding

How old of a Jewish tradition is it for a chosson and kallah to walk down the aisle at their wedding?

Comment: How else do you expect them to get there?

Comment: "Why" and "How old" are different question, as you surely are aware. What do you intend to ask? You can't write one thing in the title and one thing in the body of a question and expect people to understand...

Comment: perhaps is it a question about the Jewish character of this tradition, which perhaps appeared as an imitation of church's custom.

Comment: I surmise that the custom is as old as shuls and wedding halls have been. Assuming that the wedding scene in Fiddler on the Roof portrays a fairly decent resemblance of what was done in Europe, many weddings were done outdoors in a small square / plaza. There was no aisle. I have also been to a wedding where the chattan is already waiting under the chuppa prior to the start of the ceremony (before people are seated), and the kallah comes in from a side door near the chuppah.

Comment: @DoubleAA I think the obvious meaning of the question is about the formal ritual/custom. One doesn't generally refer to the *mesader kiddushin* as walking down the aisle, but he manages to get there too.

Comment: @sam - None of the answers given so far actually answer either question, which as far as I can tell is asking about walking down the aisle, i.e. between the men and women, and possibly asking about having people other than the chossan and kallah doing so

Answer (score 1):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 147:5 brings that the chassan is brought and the they escort the bride with many important people. The Sefer Matamim explains this idea of being escorted comes from the first marriage in history of Adam and Chava. They were escorted by two angles each. So I guess that were the idea of both parents(machlokes which parents) escorting the groom and bride.

If. I recall correctly the Midrash Rabbah mentions that when Lavan's guests were singing oy leah oy leah by the wedding the Midrash mentions the bringing of Leah,so thats a Tannaic source.

Comment: +1 So according to this there should not be an aisle, but that everyone needs to follow the bride when she comes in

Comment: This is actually what is normally done by chareidi weddings in E"Y

Answer (score 0):

The heading and body of the question differ but I believe this answers both questions.

Rav Yitzhak Meir Morgenstern cites "customs of early generations" and kabbalistic reasons for the escort. To summarize in a superficial way: The parental escort symbolizes spritual/kabbalistic ideas which are named 'Abba' and 'Imma' (these are borrowed terms). Since in Kabbalah the union between bride and groom achieves an elevation of spiritual levels, these escorts help to bestow the bride and groom the ability to achieve that unification.

> מקומות שנוהגים כמנהג קדמונים
>   שבחופה מלוים את החתן אביו
>   ואמו , שהם מרכבה לאבא ואימא עילאין (או"א)
>   והם נותנים את הכח להחתן להכנס לאור
>   הביטול, ואת הכלה מלוים אביה ואמה שהם
>   מרכבה לישסו "ת (ישראל סבא ותבונה), שהם
>   נותנים את הכח להכלה להכנס לעבודת
>   ההשתוקקות , ומנהגינו שאת החתן מלוים שני
>   האבות, שהם מרכבה בכללות לאור דאבא
>   העליון (אור הביטול – ספי' החכמה), ואת הכלה
>   מלוים ב' האמהות שהן מרכבה לאור דאמא
>   (אש ההשתוקקות – ספי' הבינה), ועי "ז נעשה
>   בחי ' ההתכללות ד 'הבן בחכמה' (בחי' אבי הכלה
>   שנכלל עם אבי החתן ) ו'חכים בבינה' (בחי' אם
>   החתן שמשתתפת עם אם הכלה), ומהתכללות זו
>   נעשה החתן מרכבה לז "א סוד התפארת הכלול
>   מקו ימין וקו שמאל, וזה סוד דברכת 'יוצר
>   האדם' – ברכת השבח על החתן שעתה הוא
>   מרכבה להז "א, (וההורים נותנים הכח לחתן וכלה
>   לעשות יחוד דאו"א בחיק ובמקום הוריהם ,